# Can metal or carbon vapour conduct electricity?

Tags: electricity, electrons, conductors, gas

> Not a duplicate of [Can Gases conduct Electricity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38631/can-gases-conduct-electricity), since it asks about ionised gases, which is irrelevant to my question.

This is what I already know:

- **All** metals have a giant metal lattice, where atoms are positive ions in a ‘sea’ of delocalised electrons, since they lose their outer (valency) electrons. The metal conducts electricity because the delocalised electrons can move throughout the structure when a voltage is applied.
- Carbon is the *only* non-metal that conducts electricity, when it is graphite, and it conducts for a similar reason that metals do.
  Only 3 out of 4 outer (valency) electrons are used in forming covalent bonds, and all of the atoms’ 4th electrons are free to move *along* the layers when a voltage is applied, carrying the current. (Current can only be carried along the layers, not throughout the structure like a metal)

I also know that metals still conduct electricity when liquid, but liquid carbon does not.

My question is this:

- Can metal vapour conduct electricity?
- Can carbon vapour conduct electricity ?

Comment: Part I answered here- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28015/structure-of-a-metal-in-gas-phase

Comment: Semiconductors are not metals, but they conduct. Vapors can certainly be ionized just fine, and can then conduct. Plasmas conduct. Clarity needed as to just what you are asking.

Comment: Is this a question about carbon arcs?

Comment: @Pieter no it isn’t. I’m asking if carbon _vapour_ or metal vapour conducts electricity.

Comment: I cannot think of any other terrestrial situation where carbon vapour would be of electrical interest. The vapour pressure is just too low.

Answer (score 3):

Metal vapors are insulators but at high density mercury vapor exhibits a metal non-metal transition: https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.40.697

Comment: What about carbon vapour?

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur See Pieter's comment to your question: "I cannot think of any other terrestrial situation where carbon vapour would be of electrical interest. The vapour pressure is just too low. – *Pieter Jan 12 at 17:12*".